# Using ORDER BY to filter results of multiple criterias in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm quite new to MySQL, and really having a hard time to write SQL script, especially those that need more than one condition like this:

DB schema consisting of the following relation schemes:

- Patient (pid, pname, age, city)
- Doctor (did, dname, city)
- Specialization (did, specialization, start_date_of_specialization)
- Clinic (cid, cname, city)
- Works_in (did, cid, hours_per_week)
- Consults (pid, did, cid, date, illness)

I have to express these queries in SQL:

1. Give details of doctors who work in clinics in “New York” but have never worked in clinics
   in “Toronto”.
2. Give the name and city of doctors who work at least a total of 60 hours a week whether
   in the same clinic or in more than one clinic.

My idea currently would be using ORDER BY statement to group some of the results together; then, filter out by HAVING statement. But this is failing when there is doctor A, worked at Toronto, but then works at New York (it adds because of the later).

```
SELECT Doctor.did, Doctor.dname, Doctor.city
FROM Doctor, Works_in, Clinic
WHERE (Doctor.did = Works_in.did) AND (Works_in.cid = Clinic.cid) 
ORDER BY Doctor.did
HAVING ...;
```

Comment: order by statement is used for sorting like asc or descending. you cannot group with "ORDER BY"

Comment: FWIW, I find `doctor_id` easier to understand than `did`

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Try these SQLs - I was not sure about mysql version you are working on. Thus I did not use any window function.

Give details of doctors who work in clinics in “New York” but have never worked in clinics in “Toronto”.

```
SELECT d.did, name, city FROM doctor d 
JOIN works_in w ON  d.did = w.did
JOIN clinic c ON c.cid = w.cid 
WHERE c.city = 'New York' AND d.did NOT IN (Select d.did from doctor d 
JOIN works_in w ON  d.did = w.did
JOIN clinic c ON c.cid = w.cid 
Where c.city = 'Toranto');
```

Give the name and city of doctors who work at least a total of 60 hours a week whether in the same clinic or in more than one clinic.

```
SELECT d.dname, c.cname FROM doctor d 
JOIN works_in w ON  d.did = w.did
JOIN clinic c ON c.cid = w.cid 
JOIN (SELECT did, SUM(hours_per_week) FROM works_in w 
GROUP BY did having SUM(hours_per_week) > 60) sum_w ON w.did = sum_w.did;
```

Comment: My version of SQL is 8.0.2. Thanks for your comment. It doesn't really work in MySQL, I dont know why, maybe because of the different versions. But I use the syntax I usually use along with your idea, then it works well!